# The ( error_log ) file size is very large

Tags: errors

The **error_log** file size of my site has been **very large**. So that it fills the entire server space.
The last error in this file:

```
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 275
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 291
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 275
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 291
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 275
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277
[06-Jul-2019 13:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 291
```

Someone can help me. What is the problem?
(**The latest changes** we have made on the site: We have used the **ACF plugin** for add custom fields.)

Comment: Turn off the plugin and watch what happens, it's not so complicated to figure out is the plugin the reason.

Comment: Is there a problem with this plugin?
We used the plugin before, but some time ago, only the fields were added to it

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the debug error loggins with this command in the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

The errors you are seeing are 'warning' (I think of them as 'benign') and have to do with coding practices not allowing for empty 'loop' variables.

You only want the WP_DEBUG to be true on development systems.

If the errors still show up, then look for that setting in the PHP ini file, or in theme or plugin functions.

Comment: Turning off debug Does not have any problems? Can not find the source of the problem? What exactly does this volume create?

Comment: Warning messages are just that, warnings. Not fatal. Usually used during development. Make sure that WP and all themes/plugins are latest versions. Could be a setting in your PHP server settings; ask your hosting support.